# How to find a full scholarship with accomodation?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, funding, computer-science

I'm trying to immigrate outside my country and found that all employers require degree certificates before work permit sponsorship.

I've dropped out of college and have been studying at home online. I don't have any college certificates apart from a recent ESL teachers course diploma certification that I got earlier this year.

So, I don't have money for education and accomodation abroad.

My Question: Are there any scholarship websites where I can post my resume and desired course and they could probably grant me a full scholarship for my studies?

I have about 3-4 open source projects that include a barcode app, a file browser app, whatsapp app and an iTunes playlist converter app...

Could anyone suggest me how to study without any initial finance? Co-op courses or full scholarships are what I'm hoping to find online..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say which country are you from? it will help a lot. 
Regarding your goal moving to the US: get in touch with foundations and the like. Private money are the way to go for the US. Otherwise, try to look into European countries as well, or South Africa, or even Australia, they may have scolarships for Bachelor students.

Comment: I'm from India. I cannot opt for a graduation degree course due to my age (36y). Hopefully any diploma or certification that could get me a placement could be much better. I've studied on udemy, coursera, YouTube, and api documentations. I only need a university certification for a placement. If not, then hopefully a scholarship to study for a short term course.

Comment: What would you mean by private money?

Comment: Foundations, rich families and companies "helping the word in getting better" and things like that. 
However, I wonder if it would not be easier for you to start your own company, looking for clients all over the world, since you have the knowledge and you can perform some work. When you save enough money, then you think about supporting yourself abroad.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I'll try and work on projects or study online for placement abroad. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full scholarships for undergraduate study in US are quite rare. They are sometimes give for extreme hardship, but mostly to US citizens. They are sometimes given for truly exceptional merit. They are also given to fairly exceptional athletes in some sports.

For an international student, I'd think that some funding originating in your own country would be a better possibility. Perhaps a company could sponsor you. Perhaps some organization that sees a need for more people educated in a certain field could help.

Doctoral study is different and most students work as a TA to finance their education and living expenses. But these are not normally available to undergraduates or even masters students.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how can you enroll in german universities, or scandinavian universities.
Some of them offer (relatively speaking) not so expensive bachelor and master courses.

If you are looking into US universities, we are talking about tuition fees being 10/20 times lower, with similar or cheaper costs of life (ok, this is a  gross assumption, Stockholm , Swedem will be more expensive than Urbana, Illinois)

Comment: They won't get a visa for Germany if they can't cover their living-costs in Germany. From their question I would deduce they don't have sufficient money or income.